# Parsing error in galaxy pop but not in nexus and emulator

Tags: android

I am testing my app and I am running it on emulator and Nexus.It's working fine but when i use samsung galaxy pop it shows parsing error.

parse error:
There is a problem in parsing the packages.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you, like code sample and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey According to me this problem is due to low API version.Galaxy pop has 2.2 froyo but in google nexus version is 4 maximum. Might be you have selected min SDK level above foryo version...Change the manifest of application and make it compatible to froyo.